# Displaying the sum value of a SQLite query in a textview as currency

Tags: android, android-studio

I have the sum total of the income column of my database displaying as a double in a textview but I can't get it to display as currency. When I debug, the results show it should display as "$ 10,432.18", but it just shows as "10432.18". Below is what I used in a listview for the individual income items that worked in the listview, but not in the textview:

```
TextView cmIncomeSumTextView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.cm_income_sum_text_view);
    DecimalFormatSymbols symbols = new DecimalFormatSymbols();
    symbols.setGroupingSeparator(',');
    symbols.setDecimalSeparator('.');
    DecimalFormat decimalFormat = new DecimalFormat("$ #,###.00", symbols);
    String cmIncomeDecimal = decimalFormat.format(cmIncomeSum());
    cmIncomeSumTextView.setText(cmIncomeDecimal);
```

any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

You can try this instead.

```
string pattern = "$###,###.###";
DecimalFormat decimalFormat = new DecimalFormat(pattern);

String format = decimalFormat.format(123456789.123);
System.out.println(format);
```